# Probability of x modulus a prime = a

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, hash-function

I am working on a project that involves analyzing the distribution of simple hash functions. One such construction relies on the fact that given a primes $p,q$, the unit group for $p$ $U_p$, a random integer $x$ and random unit $a\in U_p$, I want to show that the probability distribution of $x \cdot q \equiv a~mod~p$ is uniform, with parameter $\frac{1}{p}$ I am fairly certain in relies on the randomness of $x$ but am having trouble formally proving this.

Comment: Presumbly by "a random unit $a\in U_p$" you mean "an element of $U_p$ chosen *uniformly* at random from that finite set". What do you mean by "a random integer $x$"?

Comment: i mean choose an $x$ uniformly at random in some fixed range. I want to show that for a random $x$, $xq$ mod $p$ is randomly distributed in $U_p$

Comment: Ok: if it is possible to pick an $x$ that is a multiple of $p$, then this won't be true. So I assume that all the possible values for $x$ are units modulo $p$. Then your statement is almost true: for each value of $x$ individually, the probability of choosing $a\in U_p$ such that $xq\equiv a\pmod p$ is exactly $1/(p-1)$. (There are $p-1$ choices for $a$, and exactly one of them works, and you're choosing $a$ uniformly at random.) (Of course this also assumes that $q\ne p$, which you didn't say but I assume you intend.)